Quantum Espresso Install Linux pw_relax - relax-extfor.in: **FAILED**
I installed quantum-espresso version 7.3.1 on my linux machine. I installed all the libraries(lapack, blas, mpi, fftw3) from apt store. I installed libxc from source. I ran the tests. One test failed with following error message.
pw_relax - relax-extfor.in: **FAILED**.
Different sets of data extracted from benchmark and test.
    Data only in benchmark: geom.
eh1
    ERROR: absolute error 7.78e-02 greater than 1.00e-02. (Test: -8.5819.  Benchmark: -8.5041.)
band
    ERROR: absolute error 3.35e-01 greater than 2.00e-01. (Test: -27.2765.  Benchmark: -27.611.)
e1
    ERROR: absolute error 4.79e-01 greater than 8.00e-04. (Test: -44.061603.  Benchmark: -43.583047.)
    ERROR: relative error 1.10e-02 greater than 1.00e-04. (Test: -44.061603.  Benchmark: -43.583047.)

Has anyone faced this problem?

Hey I faced the same problem. Did you find a solution to it?
